# Codeigniter where_in JSON column

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter

i need a Codeigniter query to get results from a JSON column MYSQL table.

**Sample column data bellow.**

```
["1","2","6","4","3","5","7","9","8"]
```

Currently im using bellow code for this but it's not working.

```
$DOCUMENTS = $this->db->select('*')->where('JSON_CONTAINS(BELONG) = '.$_POST['ID'].'')->get('SOLIDARITY_REQUESTED_FILES')->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JSON_CONTAINS` function required two minimum arguments. check more details [HERE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html)

It is dangerous to add `$_POST` data into query. Codeigniter having `input` class to fetch data from `POST` request.

```
$id = $this->input->post('ID');

$DOCUMENTS = $this->db->select('*')->where("JSON_CONTAINS(BELONG, $id)>0")->get('SOLIDARITY_REQUESTED_FILES')->result_array();
```

Feel free if you need further guidance.

Comment: Now im using bellow code thats working.

`$OPTION_ID = $_POST['OPTION_ID']; echo json_encode($this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `SOLIDARITY_REQUESTED_FILES` WHERE JSON_SEARCH(BELONG, 'one', $OPTION_ID, NULL) IS NOT NULL")->result_array());`

Answer (score 0):

If your JSON formatted as array like your data, you can concatenate the ID to the commas and quotes. then TRIM the square bracket and find by LIKE statement.

```
$concat = "CONCAT(',\"',TRIM(LEADING '[' FROM TRIM(TRAILING ']' FROM BELONG)),'\",')";
$theId = ',"'.$_POST['ID'].'",';
$DOCUMENTS = $this->db->select('*')->like($concat, $theId)->get('SOLIDARITY_REQUESTED_FILES')->result_array();
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose i'm doing to get record where city_id should be in following list.
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
then following line you can add into your code

```
    $city_id_list = "1,2,6,4,3,5,7,9,8";
    $this->db->where_in('city_id', $city_id_list);
```